# WPF: Manage margin for all controls in a ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, contentpresenter

Is it possible to define the "presenting behavior" of a `ContentPresenter` so that it applies padding to its content?

Now I have a `ContentPresenter` and define the Margin on all `UserControl`s that can be part of this ContentPresenter.

The downside of this, is that it calls for repeating definitions of Margins, and the `UserControl`s are kind of dedicated to "fit" in the `ContentPresenter`.

E.g. XAML that contains the content presenter:

```
    <ContentPresenter 
        x:Name="SettingsContentPanel" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Content="{Binding ElementName=SettingsGroupSelector, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
```

And the user controls are defined as follows:

```
    <UserControl 
        <!-- left out irrelevant definitions -->
        Margin="5,5,5,5">
```

Comment: Would defining the `Margin` on the `ContentPresenter` give you the result you're after?

Comment: Oh duh.... :). Thx. (drop it as ansewr and I'll accept it, thx already!)

Comment: Will do, thought there might be something I'd missed =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the effect you're after by setting the `Margin` on your `ContentPresenter` element itself e.g:

```
<ContentPresenter 
    x:Name="SettingsContentPanel" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="2" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Content="{Binding ElementName=SettingsGroupSelector, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" 
    Margin="5,5,5,5" />
```

Also, if the `Margin` is the same on all sides, you could use the shorthand `Margin="5"`.

Hope that helps =D